# Which candidates support x position?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Would it be on topic to ask a question in the form

"Which candidates running in the US (Republican|Democratic) presidential primary for 2016 has expressed support for X position?"

What about

"Which candidate running in the US (Republican|Democratic) presidential primary for 2016 has taken the strongest stance supporting X position?"

The first seems dubious because it could end up with a long list and multiple correct answers.

The second seems dubious because it's somewhat subjective, but I like it better because the answerer could make a short case between a few contenders based on voting records and quotes from speeches.

Is there a better way to ask this kind of question for voters who feel strongly about a particular policy position?

Answer (score 2):

**"Which candidates running in the US (Republican|Democratic) presidential primary for 2016 has expressed support for X position?"**

Given that there are no other problems in the answer, I'd allow it.  In order for such a question to not be too broad, you should make sure that the type of candidates are well defined ( *notable* people for POTUS is good enough), and that "X position" is also well defined.

---

**"Which candidate running in the US (Republican|Democratic) presidential primary for 2016 has taken the strongest stance supporting X position?"**

That question is a little bit more dangerous, since it's more subjective.  Such a question is likely to get closed, but it does depend some on the details of the question.  A good rule of thumb, is that if you can imagine that there are 2 different answers that are both contradictory to each-other and "valid", then It's probably too opinion based.

Comment: #2 can be made to work if the question includes a non-ambiguous way to grade "stronger" function given any 2 versions of position fo any 2 candidates, and that it's a transitive function. E.g. "donated more money", or "formal platform plank >> mention in speech >> didn't condemn position"